# JPA/Hibernate - Using Postgre's "ANY" Function in HQL

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql

*Context: Spring Boot Starter JPA Version **3.0.2**, Hibernate Core **6.2.7.Final***

Consider the following SQL tables and corresponding Hibernate entities:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  customerids VARCHAR(8)[] UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE order (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  customerid VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  ...
);
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(...)
class Person {
  @Id
  @Column
  private int id;

  @Column
  private String name;

  @Column
//  @Type(ListArrayType.class)
  private List<String> customerIDs;
}

@Entity
@Table(...)
class Order {
  @Id
  @Column
  private int id;

  @Column
  private String customerID;
  ...
}
```

As we can see, each `Person` can have multiple `customerID`s, which are stored in a Postgres array column (I commented out Vlad Mihalcea's Hibernate Type specification, as it appears to no longer be necessary in Hibernate 6.2.7). Of course, each of these `customerID`s is completely unique.

Therefore, if we want to get all orders for a particular person, our SQL would look like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM person 
INNER JOIN order ON order.customerid = ANY(person.customerids)
WHERE person.id = :pid
```

Where `pid` is the person's ID. This statement of course executes with no issues.

My issue occurs when translating this query into Hibernate Query Language. Here's the equivelant HQL and surrounding Spring Data Repository context (please note that I'm using an unrelated join for simplicity - it's not a necessity):

```java
@Query(FROM Order o
INNER JOIN Person p ON o.customerID = FUNCTION('ANY', p.customerIDs)
WHERE p.id = :pid)
List<Order> getOrders(@Param("pid") String pid);
```

This immediately causes the following error however when starting Spring:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.JdbcType.getDefaultSqlTypeCode()" because the return value of "org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.JavaType.getRecommendedJdbcType(org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.JdbcTypeIndicators)" is null
```

Naturally, I decided instead to try using `IN(UNNEST())` instead of  `= ANY()`, as it's essentially equivalent:

```java
@Query(FROM Order o
INNER JOIN Person p ON o.customerID IN ( FUNCTION('UNNEST', p.customerIDs) )
WHERE p.id = :pid)
List<Order> getOrders(@Param("pid") String pid);
```

No semantic errors pop up when starting the server, but unfortunately, Postgres does not allow set returning functions (`UNNEST`) inside of `JOIN` conditions:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in JOIN conditions
```

Basically, my question is, **can I turn the aforementioned join statement into HQL without having to resort to native SQL?**

Final Note: I'd prefer this be done with a JOIN rather than a subselect. This is a simplified example; my real object requires checking if two columns match an ID in the "ID list" (`person.customerIDs`), and Postgres refuses to use my indexes for some reason.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think SQL's assymmetric operators are supported in HQL.

Comment: @TheImpaler hi, what are you referring to by “asymmetric operators”?

Comment: When you combine `=`, `<>`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` with `ANY` or `ALL` that's called an *assymetric operator*. It compares one value (on the left side) to multiple ones (on the right side).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to test this on Postgres, just HSQLDB, but I got as far as this SQL being produced:

```sql
select o1_0.id,o1_0.customerid from order o1_0 join person p1_0 on o1_0.customerid=any(p1_0.customerids) where p1_0.id=?
```

I created this class:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.hibernate.boot.model.FunctionContributions;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.FunctionContributor;
import org.hibernate.type.BasicType;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

public class MyFunctionContributor implements FunctionContributor {
    @Override
    public void contributeFunctions(FunctionContributions functionContributions) {
        BasicType<String> stringType = functionContributions.getTypeConfiguration()
                .getBasicTypeRegistry().resolve(StandardBasicTypes.STRING);

        functionContributions.getFunctionRegistry().registerPattern(
                "anyString", "any(?1)", stringType);
    }
}
```

I created the file `org.hibernate.boot.model.FunctionContributor` in the folder `META-INF/services` in my `resources` directory. It contains:

```
com.example.demo.MyFunctionContributor
```

I could then create the following queries (your SQL example selected from person, while your JPQL query selected from order):

```java
@Query("FROM Order o" +
        " INNER JOIN Person p ON o.customerID = anyString(p.customerIDs)" +
        " WHERE p.id = :pid")
List<Order> getOrders(@Param("pid") int pid);

@Query("FROM Person p" +
        " INNER JOIN Order o ON o.customerID = anyString(p.customerIDs)" +
        " WHERE p.id = :pid")
List<Person> getPeople(@Param("pid") int pid);
```

Trying to get strict JPQL compliance:

```java
@Query("SELECT o FROM Order o" +
        " INNER JOIN Person p ON o.customerID = FUNCTION('anyString', p.customerIDs)" +
        " WHERE p.id = :pid")
List<Order> getOrdersJpql(@Param("pid") int pid);
```

*Note:

My actual table name for Order was myorder, since HSQLDB didn't like me using order. A quick test on a different machine and it seems that Postgres doesn't like a table called order also (I guess "ORDER BY" makes "order" a reserved word).*

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In my case i had to configure `<property name="hibernate.jpa.compliance.query" value="false"/>` in persistence.xml as otherwise i always got `StrictJpaComplianceViolation: Encountered non-compliant non-standard function call [myFunction], but strict JPA compliance was requested; use JPA's FUNCTION(functionName[,...]) syntax name instead`. 
Is there any way to make this work with `<property name="hibernate.jpa.compliance.query" value="true"/>`?

Comment: Is it any different if you use this syntax?
`o.customerID = FUNCTION('anyString', p.customerIDs)` That seems to be what the error message is suggesting.

Comment: @scrhartley yes I tried the `FUNCTION('anyString', p.customerIDs)` Syntax but it got worse. Maybe i made a mistake. The result is `Strict JPA query language compliance was violated : use of implicit treat` after having found nothing about this error on google ( see https://www.google.com/search?q=%22use+of+implicit+treat%22 ) ... I ran out of ideas.

Comment: @Marc Schmid For me, I also needed to have an explicit SELECT to stop it complaining. For your problem, possibly I'd need the entire query to work out what's wrong.

Comment: @scrhartley i found the issue! The `use of implicit treat` error was caused because I was querying with my custom function a field, that does not exist on the queried class (this is because of an error in my inheritance structure). I fixed this and now it works perfect with `hibernate.jpa.compliance.query" value="true"` and the `FUNCTION('myFunction', ...)` syntax. Thanks a lot.